# play 200fps video on 30fps on iOS

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avassetreader, mpmediaplayercontroller

i'am looking for the possibility to play a video @200fps in slow motion (30fps) on the iPhone. MPMediaPlayer is no solution. the video (600frames  ~3 sec) plays in 2 sec. I would like 30fps ~ 20 sec.

i have set the currentplaybackrate(myMPMoviePlayerController) to 0.2 and 0.1 but the video lasts only 5 seconds... i have no idea why.

is it possible to play a video @200 fps on the iphone? 
is it compatible? In this [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH9-SW6)only frmats max at 30 fps are mentioned. If i convert my video to 30 fps (so i get 20 sec@30 fps) , i can not play it in realtime(6 times faster)

can i realize it in the AVFoundation Framework?

any suggestions?

thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [currentPlaybackRate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MPMediaPlayback/currentPlaybackRate) of MpMediaPlayer and specify a playback speed like this:

```
[myMPMoviePlayerController setCurrentPlaybackRate:0.2];
```

You can even reverse playback a clip with a negative value

Comment: i tryed but at 0.2 it took about 5 sec. i expected 20 sec.